# How to display static values in td column in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi all i have one table there i need to display the course report so every course has one stage so that i have 16 types of stages ex: On Hold,Asset Incomplete,SME Discussion..etc..Like 16 types i have So i would like to display 16 types in mt td column

```
<table  class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr><th class="center">#</th>
                                    <th class="center"><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=1">PHY</a></th>
                                    <th class="center"><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=2">CHE</a></th>
                                    <th class="center"><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=3">ZOO</a></th>
                                    <th class="center"><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=4">BOT</a></th>
                                    <th class="center"><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=5">MATH</a></th>
                                    <th class="center">Total</th>
                                </TR>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>On Hold</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                    <td>0</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Remaining td's i have to get count of every course and to display

Can anyone help me how can i do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your controller / model code that fetches the data and we may be able to provide a little more guidance.

Comment: Can you post the table definition and the query you're using to get the counts with please?

Comment: counts i will do i want to show that stages list in first td column as static not from db

Comment: i have 15 stage names so that 15 stage names i want to show it in td column one by one

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a variable from your controller to your view, you do so in the $data variable.

```html
//Controller
$this->load->model('mymodel);
$data['var1'] = "Some value";
$data['var2'] = "Some value";
$data['query'] = $this->mymodel->thefunction();
```

```html
//Model = mymodel
//function = thefunction(), you have to obviously create the class and function, if you don't know how to do that, let me know
$sql = "SELECT Count(courseid) as 'statusCount'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

When you now want to display those variables in your view template, call the variable by it's name, without the "$data part"

```html
//In your view
<?php
 foreach($query->result() as $row) {
   echo "<td>" . $row->statusCount . "</td>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: what i am trying is i have a table called topics there i have columns called courseid,refid,topicname,status etc...so status column dropd0wn contains 15 values that i have mentioned in front end as static so in this page i want to get the topic count for that particular stages

Comment: hi are you there?

Comment: I'm still here.

Comment: @hi i  have doubt may i ask?

Comment: Yes.  You don't need permission to ask a question.  Please ask your question.

Comment: do you have idea about working with graphs.if you have i will post my question

Comment: You should post a new question, after you've tried to use the graphing software and have a specific question about some code.  I suggest Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/  If these comments are helpful, please feel free to upvote them.

Comment: yes and can u please give me some links which is useful for me for graphs

Comment: I provided you that link in the above comment.  Here is a link within that documentation that shows all the different types of charts you can create: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

Comment: sorry didn't check properly, ok i will try once if i am facing any issue i will post question and i will share you the link here

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by taking all your `static string` as an `associative array` for example

`$arr = array(0=>'On Hold',1=>'Asset Incomplete',2=>'SME Discussion');`
and your `td` should be 
`<?php $i = 0;
foreach($data as $dt){ ?>`

`<td><?php echo $arr[$i]; ?></td>`

`<?php $i++; } ?>`

Comment: i have tried like this <tbody>
                                    ?> <tr>
                                        <?php $i = 0;
                                        foreach ($data as $dt) {
                                            ?>
                                        <td><?php echo $arr[$i]; ?></td>

                                                 <?php $i++;
                                           } ?>

Comment: but its gibving me errror as Undefined variable: data

Comment: Here `$data` is example variable, `$data` should be a `array`  coming from your `controller` 
e.g In your controller 
`$data = your array`
`$this->load->view('your_page',$data);`

Comment: Good, it might be helpful for you

Comment: depending on rows it is getting values if i have 2 rows in table it is getting 2 and if it is 3 it has displayed 3 values

Comment: how can i do  if i dont have rows also by default it has to display

Comment: You can check `empty array`  for this.

Comment: how can i do that

Comment: if you have `empty array` comes from your `controller`, you can check it on view 
via `count($data)`, `if(count($data) > 0 ) { your dynamic td }else{ your static td }`

Answer (score 0):

Please set the array with two fields.
One for Id,another for course name.

Then use `forech()` for write `<td>` in view.html.
For example:

```
forech($array as $item){  
  echo('<td><a href="ProjectView.php?course_id=".$item["id"]>$item["name"]'</a></td>') ;
}
```